# How does python version affects the usage of modules?

Tags: python, module

I am a beginner at python, I was on my macOS Mojave 10.14.6 and found out that there are two versions of python currently installed. Typing `which python` or `which python3`, I found out two different paths to use as interpreter `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/local/bin/python3`, which one should I use and how that affects the modules I have to use? I was trying to perform a simple calculation `print("5+4=",5+4)` and discovered that I must need a package using the first path.

Thank you

Comment: Python2 is not maintained anymore, forget about it, just use Python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:
Use python3. i.e. `/usr/local/bin/python3`

Their versions are different. `/usr/bin/python` is python 2.x, and `/usr/local/bin/python3` is python 3.x.

You can check the python version using following commands in your terminal:

```sh
python --version
python3 --version
```

Some of their syntaxs are different. A quick search with your favourite search engine can lead you to many detailed comparisons between python 2 and 3. For example, [Python 2 or 3? Beginners shouldn't care!](http://www.practicepython.org/blog/2017/02/09/python2-and-3.html).

Python 2 is no longer under development since January 2020 (See [Sunsetting Python 2](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/)). If you have a choice, it's better to use python 3.